# Как при удалении из базы упорядочить ID?

Tags: php, mysql

Ребята, столкнулся с такой проблемкой. При удалении строки из таблицы, ID, у которого свойство "автоинкремент", продолжает дальше увеличивать свое значение. Из-за этого в столбце ID происходят разрывы между значениями. Например: (было) 1,2,3,4,5,6; после удаления/добавления такая картина: 1,2,3,4,7,8. Какие нужно предпринять действия для исправления этого? 
Заранее благодарен =)

Comment: ОМГ, очередной эстет :DDD

С этим бороться бессмысленно.

Comment: Да, обычно нету смысла.
Или надо иначе пересчитывать все id (что на больших БД будет нагрузочно) и менять их во всех связанных полях...хардкор.

Comment: =) ну тогда  понятно))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В дальнейшем картина у вас будет только ухудшатся со временем научитесь игнорировать это и как было сказано выше с этим просто нету смысла мучится. П.С. Хотя помню сам раньше таким вопросом задавался =)

Comment: Ну да, это как в басне, с начало будешь жить бедно потом привыкнешь.